# Pathfinding towards a moving target in 2D Platformer

Tags: path-finding

I have an enemy in my 2D platformer that chases the player around the level.

I implemented a modified version of A* that works with gravity as described here: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-adapt-a-pathfinding-to-a-2d-grid-based-platformer-theory--cms-24662

But for a moving target I would have to calculate a new path whenever the target moves. Of course I'm going to run the pathfinding on a separate thread and only once a second or something like that, but it's still a waste to calculate the path from scratch.

So I found this algorithm for transforming the old path to the new path with the new start and target position called FRA* http://idm-lab.org/bib/abstracts/papers/ijcai09b.pdf

However the platformer version of A* has a kind of 3D grid where nodes with different jump values in the same 2D location has a different z-coordinate.

Is it possible to use FRA* when jump values comes into play? Do I have to recalculate jump values?